# How to select one record or first test name only from each department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How I can select first test name only from each department, now the select show all tests names in each department but I need first test name only and one row only for each department. This is the SELECT statement:

```
  SELECT  distinct departments.dept_name,
  coalesce(groups.groupdesc,labtests.testname) AS 'Test Name',   
  LAB_RESULTS.order_id , 
  lab_results.patient_no , 
  Patients.Age as 'Age',
  case gender when 2 then 'Male' when 3 then 'Female' end as Gender

    FROM lab_results 
    inner join patients on lab_results.patient_no = patients.patient_no
    inner join labtests on lab_results.testid = labtests.testid
    inner join customers on lab_results.custid = customers.custid
    inner join Departments on lab_results.deptid = departments.dept_id
    inner join Lab_Sample_status on LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = [Lab_Sample_status].status_id
    inner join lab_orders on lab_results.order_id = lab_orders.order_id
    left join  groups on lab_results.testid = groups.testid
    WHERE lab_results.sample_status in (4,5)
    and lab_results.order_id=2000000302
    order by Departments.Dept_name
```

The output:

```
dept_name               Test Name                order_id   patient_no  Age Gender
Clinical Chemistry Unit Albumin                2000000302   11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit Calcium                2000000302   11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit Glucose Fasting (FBS)   2000000302  11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit Iron (Fe)               2000000302  11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit KIDNEY FUNCTION TEST    2000000302  11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit LIPID PROFILE           2000000302  11           45 Male
Clinical Chemistry Unit LIVER FUNCTION TEST     2000000302  11           45 Male
Hematology Unit CBC WITH DIFFERENTIAL COUNT     2000000302  11           45 Male
Hematology Unit Erythrocyte Sedimentation Rate (ESR)    2000000302  11   45 Male
Hormones Unit   Free T4 (FT4)                   2000000302  11           45 Male
Hormones Unit   Glycated Haemoglobin (HbA1c)    2000000302  11           45 Male
Hormones Unit   Thyroid Stimulating Hormone (TSH) 2000000302    11       45 Male
Hormones Unit   Vitamin B12                      2000000302 11           45 Male
Hormones Unit   Vitamin D Total                  2000000302 11           45 Male
Parasitology    URINE ANALYSIS                    2000000302    11       45 Male
Serology Unit   Helicobacter Pylori Abs in blood  2000000302    11       45 Male
```

when I remove the test name column

```
coalesce(groups.groupdesc,labtests.testname) AS 'Test Name'
```

its working correct and get one row for each department but I need the test name and select only first test name in each department like this output:

```
Clinical Chemistry Unit Albumin                2000000302   11           45 Male
Hematology Unit CBC WITH DIFFERENTIAL COUNT     2000000302  11           45 Male
Hormones Unit   Free T4 (FT4)                   2000000302  11           45 Male
Parasitology    URINE ANALYSIS                    2000000302    11       45 Male
Serology Unit   Helicobacter Pylori Abs in blood  2000000302    11       45 Male
```

How to do that please?

Comment: how do you define first test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below query list result based on the orderid and department.

```
select dept_name, [Test Name], order_id, patient_no, [Age], Gender
from (
        SELECT departments.dept_name,
            coalesce(groups.groupdesc,labtests.testname) AS 'Test Name',   
            LAB_RESULTS.order_id , 
            lab_results.patient_no , 
            Patients.Age as 'Age',
            case gender when 2 then 'Male' when 3 then 'Female' end as Gender,
            Row_number()over(Partition by departments.dept_name, LAB_RESULTS.order_id order by departments.dept_name, coalesce(groups.groupdesc,labtests.testname)) rno      
            FROM lab_results 
            inner join patients on lab_results.patient_no = patients.patient_no
            inner join labtests on lab_results.testid = labtests.testid
            inner join customers on lab_results.custid = customers.custid
            inner join Departments on lab_results.deptid = departments.dept_id
            inner join Lab_Sample_status on LAB_RESULTS.SAMPLE_STATUS = [Lab_Sample_status].status_id
            inner join lab_orders on lab_results.order_id = lab_orders.order_id
            left join  groups on lab_results.testid = groups.testid
            WHERE lab_results.sample_status in (4,5)
            and lab_results.order_id=2000000302

    )a where rno=1
    order by dept_name
```

Comment: another thing when remove the condition  and lab_results.order_id=2000000302 and select all orders its not bring all orders and bring one row only from each order ?

Comment: Yes it will bring only one row for all department only with rno=1 condition. i have used departments.dept_name partition in Row_number function

Comment: can you please add the answer if I need to select all order_id in lab_results and not only one order without this condition and lab_results.order_id=2000000302 and show one row for each department for each order_id ?